# If a cell value exist in a column excel

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have 3 columns in excel :

```
 A               B              C  
CompanyID      Formula        Exists? 
ABC            ABC + 2         True
DEF            HHH + DEF       True   
HHH            1 + 3           True
EEE            ABC + 7         False 
               ABC + 4          
               4+1
```

If the CompanyID exists in formula, it will show true on the exists column.

I've tried =vLookup(A1,B:B,1,True) it does not work, it returns me the value even though it does not exists.

I'm going nuts. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=COUNTIF(B:B,"*"&A1&"*")>0` will do.

The asterisk represents strings of any length.